# Rails Mysql Installation on MacOS - CMake Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, xcode, cmake

I've got an issue with the installation of mysql for Ruby on Rails on MacOS Snow Leopard.
I follow the tutorial on this website http://michaelfarmer.info/preferred-rails-3-and-mysql-installation-on-o.
At the step of mysql installation (brew install mysql), the Terminal exposes an error which is:

> CMake Error: Parse error in cache file /tmp/homebrew-cmake-2.8.4-fYTo/cmake-2.8.4/CMakeCache.txt. Offending entry: /SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk

I found out that the problem comes from the fact that Xcode is not installed in the default directory "/Developer". As it is explained here : https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/5182

At this point, I'm completely lost, what am I supposed to do now ?

Here's my brew --config

> HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
>   HEAD: (none)
>   HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
>   HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
>   HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
>   HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
>   Hardware: dual-core 64-bit core2
>   OS X: 10.6.7
>   Kernel Architecture: i386
>   Ruby: 1.8.7-174
>   /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   Xcode: 3.2.5
>   GCC-4.0: build 5494
>   GCC-4.2: build 5664
>   LLVM: build 2333
>   MacPorts or Fink? false
>   X11 installed? true

Thanks in advance for any help.
Camille.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to, you could make a symbolic link from the path you have Xcode installed at to `/Developer`:

```
ln -s /path/to/xcode /Developer
```

And then CMake (and MySQL) will compile. (I keep Xcode on a secondary drive since my primary is a tiny SSD, and this worked for me).

Comment: Just to clarify, after doing the symbolic link, you should see an `SDKs` folder under `/Developer`

Comment: Yes, the folder is there. Anyway it seems that creating the symbolic link raises a problem. The proper solution is to install XCode in the Developer folder. Thanks dmarkow.